# Reading and processing parallelism in Kafka Spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to parallelize reading of Kafka messages thereby processing them in parallel. My Kafka topic has 10 partitions. I'm trying to create 5 DStreams and applying `Union` method to operate on a single DStream. Here is the code I tried so far:

```
  def main(args: scala.Array[String]): Unit = {

    val properties = readProperties()

    val streamConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("KafkaStream")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(streamConf, Seconds(1))
    //  println("defaultParallelism: "+ssc.sparkContext.defaultParallelism)
    ssc.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
    val numPartitionsOfInputTopic = 5
    val group_id = Random.alphanumeric.take(4).mkString("consumer_group")
    val kafkaStream = {
      val kafkaParams = Map("zookeeper.connect" -> properties.getProperty("zookeeper_connection_str"),
                            "group.id" -> group_id,
                            "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "3000")                      

      val streams = (1 to numPartitionsOfInputTopic).map { _ =>
                          KafkaUtils.createStream[scala.Array[Byte], String, DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder](
                          ssc, kafkaParams, Map("kafka_topic" -> 1), StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER).map(_._2)
      }
    val unifiedStream = ssc.union(streams)
    val sparkProcessingParallelism = 5 
    unifiedStream.repartition(sparkProcessingParallelism)
    }

  kafkaStream.foreachRDD { x => 
  x.foreach {       
      msg => println("Message: "+msg)
      processMessage(msg)
   }      
  }

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

Upon execution, it's not even receiving a single message, let alone processing it further. Am I missing something here? Please suggest for changes if required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to switch to Direct Stream. Why?

Direct Stream by default sets the parallelism to the number of partition you have in Kafka. Nothing more must be done - just create Direct Stream and do your job :)

If you create 5 DStreams, you will by default read in 5 thread, one non-Direct-DStream = one thread

Comment: Hi Gaweda, thanks for suggesting an alternative. I just tried Direct Stream method. Still, the messages are getting processed one after the other. The processing time is actually less than a second. In order to test it, I had put `Thread.sleep(10000)` in the message processing function. Here is the map of KafkaParams that I'm forming:
`val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list"           ->  localhost:9092, 
                          "group.id"                       ->  "dsdc", 
                          "auto.offset.reset"              ->  "largest")`
Do I need to change something here?